# If two time complexity classes are equal what does that imply about the time complexity classes for corresponding proper complexity functions?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Say that two complexity classes are equal, i.e. `TIME(n) = TIME(nlogn)`. Does this imply that for some proper complexity function `f(n) >= n` we can show `TIME(f(n)) = TIME(f(n)(logf(n)))`? If so, how can we strongly argue that they are equal and one is not just strictly contained in the other?

Comment: Are you familiar with the technique of *padding*?

Answer (score 1):

Proving such theorems are usually done with the technique known as [padding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument).

In your particular case, if we assume that "proper" funtions are functions we are used to (i.e, [time constructible](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function)) then the statement is incorrect.

Let us assume this is note the case, and that the theorem is correct. Now, if $f(n)$ is some time-constructible function, then $TIME(f(n))=TIME(f(n)\log(f(n)))$.

Denote $g(n):=f(n)\log(f(n))$ and notice that $g(n)$ is a time-constructible function as well. Thus $TIME(f(n))=TIME(g(n))=TIME(g(n)\log(g(n)))$

But notice that $h(n):=g(n)\log(g(n))=f(n)\log(f(n))\cdot \left( \log(f(n))+\log(\log(f(n)))\right)$ is much larger than $f(n)\log(f(n))$ in the sense that $f(n)\log(f(n))=o(h(n))$.

Therefore, by the [time heirarchy theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), $TIME(f(n))\subsetneq TIME(h(n))$, but this contradicts our assumption that $TIME(f(n))=TIME(g(n))=TIME(h(n))$.

Thus we finally proved that this statement is incorrect. A similar proof may be utilized even if $TIME(f(n))=TIME(f(n)\log^\epsilon (f(n))$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.